# react accordion - can open only a single one but can't close the one that is currently open

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm building an accordion (questions and answers). I have 2 requirements here.

1. Only one question can be displayed at a time (the others must be closed) I've successfully handled this. only matching ID is being displayed.

HOWEVER, my problem here is that **'I can't close the one that is currently being displayed!'**
The only way to close the DISPLAYED one at the moment is to open another one :D
I've tried to add memoryState and cache current id etc... and also tried to use more complex ternaries and so forth. but I'm kinda lost. I feel like I'm missing a simple piece here...
(I'm tryna build up on a tutorial)

// App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import data from './data';
import SingleQuestion from './Question';
function App() {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(data);

    const [idFlag, setIdFlag] = useState(null);

    const toggleAnswer = (id) => {
        setIdFlag(id);
    };

    return (
        <main>
            <div className='container'>
                <h3>Questions and Answers About Login</h3>
                <div>
                    {questions.map((question) => {
                        // const { id, title, info } = question;
                        return (
                            <SingleQuestion
                                {...question}
                                toggleAnswer={toggleAnswer}
                                idFlag={idFlag}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

export default App;
```

// SingleQuestion

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AiOutlineMinus, AiOutlinePlus } from 'react-icons/ai';
const Question = ({ id, title, info, toggleAnswer, idFlag }) => {
    // const [memory, setMemory] = useState({});

    return (
        <>
            <div className='question' key={id}>
                <header>
                    <h4>{title}</h4>
                    <button
                        className='btn'
                        onClick={() => {
                            toggleAnswer(id);
                        }}
                    >
                        {id === idFlag ? <AiOutlineMinus /> : <AiOutlinePlus />}
                    </button>
                </header>
                <p>{id === idFlag && info}</p>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Question;
```

// Data

```
const questions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Do I have to allow the use of cookies?',
    info:
      'Unicorn vinyl poutine brooklyn, next level direct trade iceland. Shaman copper mug church-key coloring book, whatever poutine normcore fixie cred kickstarter post-ironic street art.',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'How do I change my My Page password?',
    info:
      'Coloring book forage photo booth gentrify lumbersexual. Migas chillwave poutine synth shoreditch, enamel pin thundercats fashion axe roof party polaroid chartreuse.',
  },
]

export default questions
```

Comment: You can add a new key on the question array of objects... let say .. isOpen.. then .. this will be your basis if they're open or not ... You will update this each time the accordion is clicked based on the id.

Comment: You need a Boolean on each question which can be either open/close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the active flag to `null` (That is the default/initial value for the flag and does not match with the id of any question) again if the question is already active:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { AiOutlineMinus, AiOutlinePlus } from 'react-icons/ai';

const Question = ({ id, title, info, toggleAnswer, idFlag }) => {
  const isThisActive = id === idFlag;
  return (
    <>
      <div className="question" key={id}>
        <header>
          <h4>{title}</h4>
          <button
            className="btn"
            onClick={() => {
              toggleAnswer(isThisActive ? null : id);
            }}
          >
            {isThisActive ? <AiOutlineMinus /> : <AiOutlinePlus />}
          </button>
        </header>
        <p>{isThisActive && info}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Question;
```